# Слово "звуджений". Етимолоґія. Синоніми

Tags: етимологія, синоніми, невідоме-слово

У Домонтовича в "Дівчині з ведмедиком" побачив слово "звуджений":

1. "звуджену скумбрію" - подумав, що її хтось спіймав вудкою.
2. "звуджену шинку" - зрозумів, що подумав неправильно.

Ґуґл видає всього кілька результатів на:

1. [Звуджений](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&oq=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.1351j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) - 5 результатів.
2. [Звуджувати](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B6%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8&nfpr=1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiq7tO9tvXYAhUKblAKHVI6AWkQvgUIJSgB&biw=1366&bih=662) - 2 результати.

Українською чи англійською мовою результатів не бачу.

Бачу ще ["звуджений шмат оленини"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=SrwCDgAAQBAJ&pg=PT101&lpg=PT101&dq=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=e0sJkUnP42&sig=kCq3s2F1vqIXGT9ZxPv6woJMjnE&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjBs7fevPXYAhUObVAKHa1wDHEQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D1%88%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%20%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8&f=false), що натякає на копченість чи щось таке.

Чи в когось є українські джерела з поясненням цього слова, його етимолоґії, синонімами?

Comment: Comments are not designed for (semi-)answering questions. Removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Словник української мови: в 11 томах](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85)

[Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 781.](http://sum.in.ua/s/vudzhenyj)

> **ву́джений**, а, е. *Дієприкметник пасивного стану минулого часу* до **вудити**
>
> 2. *Мій знайомий чомусь нагадує рибу, тільки вуджену* (Мирослав Ірчан, II, 1958, 164); 
>      //  *у значенні прикметника* *Рожни крутилися над вогнем з шматками вудженого сала* (Михайло Томчаній, Готель.., 1960, 258).

[Том 1, 1970. — Стор. 781—782.](http://sum.in.ua/s/vudyty)

> **вудити** джу, диш, *недоконаний вид*, *перехідне дієслово*.
>
> 1. Ловити вудкою рибу. *[Влас:] Простудився, через те тепер і рибу не ходжу вудити* (Марко Кропивницький, II, 1958, 320); *На Дінці я мав свій затишний куточок, де любив вудити рибу* (Олександр Копиленко, Як вони.., 1948, 59).
>      ♦ **Вудити рибу в каламутній воді** — робити щось вигідне для себе, скориставшись сприятливими обставинами; **Носом рибу вудити** — дрімати.
> 2. *рідко* Те саме, що **закопчувати** *І ще через одно наше місто славне: тут вудять дуже смачні шинки* (Осип Маковей, Вибр., 1954, 194).

---

[Етимологічний словник української мови](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8) — частина 1, сторінка 437

> **ву́ди́ти** «коптити, закопчувати (мʼясо та інше)»,
>
> *вуджени́на*, *вужени́на*, *вуджа́рня* — *Желехівський Є.*, *Недільський С*. Малоруський-німецький словар. Т. 1—2. Львів, 1886;
>
> білоруська *вэ́ндзіць* (з польської), польська wędzić, чеська uditi, uzenina, словацька údiť, словенська vodíti;
>
> прасловʼянська *vǫditi «обкурювати, консервувати димом мʼясо, рибу, сир»;
>
> споріднене з *vędnǫti «вʼянути»; індоєвропейська u̯ondh-/u̯endh- «вʼянути, сохнути, зникати»;
>
> зіставляється ще (Machek ESJČ 666) з *ве́дро* «сонячно», давньоверхньонімецька swedan «палити помалу з великим димом».
>
> ЭСБМ 2 296; Brückner 608–609; Holub—Кор. 401.
>
> Порівняйте **буди́ти**, **вʼядчина́**, **вʼя́нути**.